# Making an UILabel appear in another view once pressed in one view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have 2 views

- SoundViewController
- ShowViewController

The sound view has a sound on it (IBAction).

```
- (IBAction)oneSound:(id)sender; {
    if (oneAudio && oneAudio.playing) {
        [oneAudio stop];
        [oneAudio release];
        oneAudio = nil;
        return;
    }    
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1k" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if (oneAudio) [oneAudio release];
    NSError *error = nil;
    oneAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    oneAudio.delegate = self;
    [oneAudio play];
```

mainText.text =@"test";

```
}
```

And the ShowViewController needs to display the uilabel thats been pressed from the sound button

I want it so once the user has pressed the sound on SoundViewController, the uilabel appear on the showviewcontroller as it appear on the soundviewcontroller at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do this by

1. retain the UILabel
2. remove it from it's superview
3. add it to the other view
4. release it

You'll need access to the `ShowViewController` from the `SoundViewController`. So you'll have to define a connection between the two views (via IBOutlet or retained property, most likely).

I'm not sure what variable in the above code is your UILabel, so replace 'sender' with the correct ivar (`mainLabel`, maybe?):

```
[sender retain];
[sender removeFromSuperview];
[showViewController.view addSubview:sender];
[sender release];
```

Edit:

To clarify, the variable in the above code "sender" is the object that triggered this method. Whatever you have connected to the IBAction in the nib. In this case it would probably be a UIButton. You probably have to add an IBOutlet for your UILabel, and attach it to the correct UILabel in your nib file and use that IBOutlet in place of "sender".

You should probably read up on view hierarchy and view controllers. What you're trying to do is remarkably easy, and there are about a dozen ways to make it happen, but you have to understand how to structure your app correctly first. The most obvious issue is that the two view controllers need to have a reference to each-other in order to pass views back and forth. I can't send a view to another view if I don't know where that other view is. The views can be connected in IB, in code when they are created, etc.

`view` is a property of `UIViewController`. Assuming your `ShowViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, it will have a `view` property. Perhaps your showViewController ivar isn't correctly typed? (if the type is `id` for example, it will give a warning when you try to access it's `view` property).

Comment: Hi, I'm still kinda confused. I've decided to create another IBAction and link it to the same button in the SoundViewController. And this is the code in the SoundViewController 
- (IBAction)showText:(id)sender;
{
mainText.text=@"Test text";
    [sender retain];
    [sender removeFromSuperview];
    [showViewController.view addSubview:sender];
    [sender release];
}  But it gives me an error of Property 'view' not found on object of type 'showViewController'. And also how would you link the mainText on soundviewcontroller to the showviewcontroller?

Comment: @LA1 edited to add more information. Sounds like you're missing some fundamentals on view controllers and view hierarchy to me. Without understanding those, it's hard to clearly explain. Sorry.